# Why doesn't the proof of the Urysohn lemma go through if we have a regular space only?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading James Munkres. The author writes, page 211, that take a point $a$ and a closed set $B$ not containing $a$. Define $U_1 = X - B$ and choose the open set $U_0$ about $a$ whose closure is contained in $U_1$ (using regularity of $X$). Suppose $p$ is the next rational after $0$ and $1$. You want an open set $U_p$ such that $\text{Cl} \, U_0 \subset U_p$ and $\text{Cl} \, U_p \subset U_1$. For this, regularity is not enough. My question is, why is regularity not enough?

Comment: Because we need an open set $U$ with $\overline{U}_0 \subset U \subset \overline{U}\subset U_1$. So you want to separate the disjoint closed sets $\overline{U}_0$ and $X\setminus U_1$ by disjoint open sets. That requires $T_4$ (well, in specific situations it can be possible also without $T_4$, but to know that it is always possible requires $T_4$).

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see. Thanks for your help!